# How to uninstall java from sco openserver 5.0.6?

Tags: java, sco, openserver

I have installed Java (J2SE 1.3.1_21) by following this tutorial:

http://www.anyang-window.com.cn/in-the-sco-openserver-506-installed-on-j2se-13106-development-environment/

Now, I want to uninstall it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Not guaranteed to work, but if you used pkgadd to add the software, use pkgrm to remove it.

```
$ pkginfo {package_name} 
$ pkgrm {package_name}
```

See if you can find the sco opensever [release notes](ftp://ftp.sco.com/pub/unixware7/713/other/java_131.22/ReleaseNotes.html) for your version of java for how to uninstall.